# How to select sqlite order by char and number key?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Some value of col in sqlite database:

```
a1b2
a2b3
a1b10
a10b1
```

if use `order by` in sql it will be:

```
a10b1
a1b10
a1b2
a2b3
```

I want it like `NSNumericSearch` of objc like this:

```
a1b2
a1b10
a2b3
a10b1
```

How do I write the SQL statements?

Comment: That isn't built into SQLite. You will need to write your own custom collator, install it into your database, and specify that collator in your "order by".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by creating a custom collating function:

```
int compare_natural(void *data, int len1, const void *str1, int len2, const void *str2) {
    if (str1 && len1 > 0 && str2 && len2 > 0) {
        NSString *s1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)str1 length:len1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding freeWhenDone:NO];
        NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)str2 length:len2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding freeWhenDone:NO];

        // The use of NSNumericSearch is required for your need.
        // The others are options depending on your needs
        NSComparisonResult res = [s1 compare:s2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSNumericSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];

        return res;
    } else if (str1 && len1 > 0 && (!str2 || len2 == 0)) {
        return -1; // empty strings to the end of the list (optional)
    } else if (str2 && len2 > 0 && (!str1 || len1 == 0)) {
        return 1; // empty strings to the end of the list (optional)
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then register the custom collator. This needs to be done after you open the database.

```
// dbRef is your sqlite3 database reference
int rc = sqlite3_create_collation(dbRef, "BYNUMBER", SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &compare_natural);
```

Then update your query so it ends with "COLLATE BYNUMBER"

> SELECT some_col ORDER BY some_col COLLATE BYNUMBER;

Comment: That's slick! More code to write but still a very cool approach.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Thanks. The nice thing is that is it reusable and if you have more than one query that you need to sort this way, it's actually easier.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you very much, I have try this way, but got a error `near "NATURAL": syntax error`

Comment: Dear @rmaddy , I change the word `NATURAL` to something else, it WORK! thank you very much. if use key named `NATURAL`, it syntax error all time.

Comment: Oops. Didn't realize NATURAL is reserved.